# codeigniter cookie helper combined with session helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, setcookie

Is it possible to run both session and cookie helpers? Cause I am trying and I can't get a cookie to set for the life of me, no matter what method I try either falling CI's docs to the letter and doing it there way or attempting to work with cookies through native php alone. Either way I try cookies will not set.

I have tried to set them like:

```
$this->input-set_cookie('AutoRemember', $mID.'-'.$hashbrown, $shortlife);
and
setcookie('AutoRemember', $mID.'-'.$hashbrown, $shortlife);
```

and I have tried to work with them like

```
echo $this->input->cookie('AutoRemember');
and
echo $_COOKIE['AutoRemember'];
```

the cookie helper is auto loaded just as is the session one, so they are loaded. session helper works like a charm, but the cookies I got nothing but a headache. All I want to do is set a cookie so I can have a "remember me" function on my site, and what should be a 5 minute deal to do, has taken me hours of various ways of passing it either by setting something for a view to pick up so it can set it in a view, or setting it in the controller and nothing.

Doesn't appear to be a browser issue either as both Chrome, and FireFox seem to not have a cookie getting stored anywhere.

So is it something with using both sessions and cookies or is codeigniter garbage when it comes to setting a cookie and kills the effort no matter which way you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through some of the Expression Engine code (an app shipped by Ellis Labs that uses CI) they are calling the PHP native `setcookie` function in their `set_cookie` function, so perhaps this is the way to go.

Looks like there should be no problem having the cookie helper running in tandem with the Session library.  That said it's worth noting the Session class is calling `setcookie` directly rather than using the cookie helper (way to reuse code CI!).

In general, calling the PHP function `setcookie` should bypass any CI stuff and work no matter what, so if that isn't working maybe something else is going on.  Best bet is probably to start with `setcookie` and try to get that working.

Check the return value from `setcookie`, if it's `false` output has already been started and that's why it isn't working; could be the same issue you're running into trying the CI cookie helper too.

Comment: I don't believe I am outputting anywhere prior to the call to set_cookie/setcookie I do have an echo statement after the fact but if theres something before I'm doubtful, how would one check to see if theres output before the cookie/sessions, typically you'd get a headers sent error if there was output prior right?

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do at first would be check the result of `setcookie`, `if(!setcookie(...)) { // output must be starting somewhere else }`